# What is the simplest way to find out if a set contains maps with given key values in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

I really like using `contains?` because it's so terse and readable. I want to see if a set contains maps that have the same key and value pairs of an example that also had other key value pairs. I'm pretty sure `contains?` won't work here. Is there an alternative? Maybe I'll have to write one (I'm finally getting into the mindset!). For example, if I had

```
(def some-set #{{:foo "bar" :beep "boop"}{:foo "bar"} {:foo "bar" :hi "there"}})
```

what would be a quick way to know if it had any maps that matched `{:foo "bar" :one "two"}` on `:foo "bar"`?

Answer (score 6):

*Edited:* Remembering that a map is a collection of key-value vectors, here is an implementation for the predicate `submap?`:

```clj
(defn submap?
  "Returns true if subm is a submap of m, false otherwise."
  [subm m]
  (every? (fn [[k v]] (= (get m k ::not-found) v)) subm))
```

This predicate can be used to filter any collection:

```clj
(filter #(submap? {:a 1 :b 2} %) [{:a 1} {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}])
=> ({:a 1, :b 2, :c 3})
```

## Original answer

This solution works but is slower than my updated answer, due to the construction of `(set m)` for large `m`

```clj
(defn submap?
  "Returns true if subm is a submap of m, false otherwise."
  [subm m]
  (let [kvs (set m)]
    (every? kvs subm)))
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm going to try it out now.

Answer (score 1):

A generic way would be to write a predicate, that checks if a map
contains another map.  This can be done using `select-keys` to only get
a map with certain keys; using the `keys` from the map to compare and
then just comparing the result will give you that.

```
(def maps #{{:foo "bar" :beep "boop"} {:foo "bar"} {:foo "bar" :hi "there"} {:foo "baz"}})

(defn submap?
  [submap m]
  (= (select-keys m (keys submap)) submap))

(println
  (filter (partial submap? {:foo "bar"}) maps))
; → ({:foo bar, :beep boop} {:foo bar, :hi there} {:foo bar})
```

Yet this is just a simple sequential search.  This does not (and AFAIR
there is nothing in core to help) utilize your maps being in a set.
Also note, that the order of the result is undefined since the order of
sets is too.

Comment: Awesome! I used to think, oh... geez... I have to write it, but now I'm getting into making my own little utilities (with all of your help). I also appreciate Alan's library suggestion. A little of both will be the key thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can find many predicates of this nature and related helper functions in [the Tupelo library](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/21.04.13/api/tupelo.core), in particular:

- submap?
- submatch?
- wild-match?
- wild-submatch?

These are especially helpful in writing unit tests. For example, you may only care about certain fields like `:body` when testing a webserver response, and you want to ignore other fields like the IP address or a timestamp.

[The unit tests](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/cljc/tst/tupelo/core.cljc#L2960) show the code in action.

Comment: I've seen Tupelo a lot and am going to look at it now. Thank you also for showing where I can see it being used... very helpful!